# How can I prevent Gnome from intercepting the Alt+Shift+~ key?

Tags: emacs, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome

I often want to type Alt+Shift+~ while using emacs (to run its command "not-modified").  However, since upgrading to Debian Wheezy (which upgraded Gnome to 3.4), I find that when I type those keys, Emacs doesn't "hear" the keystroke; instead, I see a popup window that looks like the window I see when I hit Alt+TAB (except this window only ever has a single icon in it, for Emacs, as opposed to the window that Alt+TAB brings up, which has one icon for each application).

I've fixed many similar stolen-keystroke problems like this in the obvious way: I click my name in the upper-right corner of the screen, choose "System Settings" from the dropdown menu; click the "Keyboard" icon, click the "Shortcuts" tab, and examine every entry on the right side to see if it's the guilty party; if so, I disable it.  However, in this particular case, I cannot find any entry that refers to the tilde or the backtick key, so I don't know what to delete.

I've also tried examining the output of `gconftool-2 --recursive-list` to see if I could find anything likely, but saw nothing that looked relevant.

Answer (score 9):

Some diligent googling for "gnome alt backtick" found this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['disabled']"
```

I found it at https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/992928/comments/4

Comment: I had same issue in ubuntu. Managed to [solve it using CompizConfig](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014673/window-switching-keyboard-shortcuts-interfere-with-emacs-and-cannot-be-changed-i), which may or may not be relevant here.

Comment: After running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['disabled']"` my GNOME on Wayland still intercepts Ctlr-, and displays the `e` character. Very very annoying. I wonder if this is Wayland specific. Clues anyone?